# Randomização em Jogo da Memória

Tags: java

Como posso trabalhar nesse código abaixo para que em vez de aparecer números nos botões apareçam imagens?

```
package memory;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class Memory extends JFrame{


    int pontos = 100; 

    Random RandomNumber = new Random(); 
    int Aleatorio[] = new int [16];
    int Posicao_do_vetor_Aleatorio[] = new int [16];

    // Barra de Ferramenta
    private final JToolBar Barra_Ferramenta = new JToolBar();

    private final JButton Button_Novo_Jogo = new JButton("Novo Jogo");
    //private JButton Button_Estatisticas = new JButton("Estatísticas")
    private final JButton Escolha[] = new JButton[16];

    private final JPanel Panel = new JPanel();
    private final JPanel Barra_de_Status = new JPanel();

    private final GridLayout Layout_do_Jogo = new GridLayout(4,4); 
    private final Font Fonte = new Font("Lucida Console", Font.BOLD, 36);

    private final JLabel Pontuacao_do_Jogador = new JLabel("Pontos: 100");

    public Memory() {
        super("Jogo da Memória");

        Barra_Ferramenta.add(Button_Novo_Jogo);
        //Barra_Ferramenta.add(Button_Estatisticas);///////////JTOOLBAR/////////
        add(Barra_Ferramenta, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        for (int i=0; i<16; ++i){
            Escolha[i] = new JButton();
            Panel.add(Escolha[i]);
            Escolha[i].setFont(Fonte);
            Escolha[i].setVisible(true);
        }

        Panel.setLayout(Layout_do_Jogo);
        add(Panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        Barra_de_Status.add(Pontuacao_do_Jogador);
        add(Barra_de_Status, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        Eventos_JogoDaMemoria Handler = new Eventos_JogoDaMemoria();
        for (int i=0; i<16; ++i){
            Escolha[i].addActionListener(Handler);
        }
        Button_Novo_Jogo.addActionListener(Handler);
        //Button_Estatisticas.addActionListener(Handler);///////////////////////



        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);     
        this.setSize(500,500);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private class Eventos_JogoDaMemoria implements ActionListener{

        int Cont_Acertos,Primeiro_Click,Segundo_Click;
        int Numero_Click, posi, cont, pontos_Anterior, Maior_Pontuacao_do_Jogador;
        int Partidas_jogadas = 0, Numero_de_Vitorias = 0;
        boolean Novo_Jogo = true;
        boolean Re_Iniciar = false;
        boolean Fim_de_Jogo = false;                       


        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){                       



            if (event.getSource() == Button_Novo_Jogo){
                Novo_Jogo = true; ///
                Re_Iniciar = false;
            }

            //if (event.getSource() == Button_Estatisticas){
            // Fim_de_Jogo = true;
            //}

            if (Novo_Jogo == true){ 

                Cont_Acertos = 0;
                Partidas_jogadas++;
                pontos_Anterior = pontos;
                pontos = 100;
                Numero_Click = 0;
                posi = 0; cont = 16;
                Primeiro_Click = 0;
                Segundo_Click = 0;

                for (int i=0; i<16; ++i){

                    Escolha[i].setText("");
                    Escolha[i].setEnabled(true);
                }


                if (Re_Iniciar == false){

                    for (int i=0; i<16; ++i){
                        Posicao_do_vetor_Aleatorio[i] = i;
                    }

                    for (int i=0; i<8; ++i){

                        for (int j=0; j<2; ++j){
                            posi = RandomNumber.nextInt(cont);
                            Aleatorio[Posicao_do_vetor_Aleatorio[posi]] = i;

                            if (posi < cont){
                                for (int q=(posi+1); q<(cont); ++q){
                                    Posicao_do_vetor_Aleatorio[q-1] = Posicao_do_vetor_Aleatorio[q];
                                }
                            } cont--;
                        }
                    }
                }


                Novo_Jogo = false;
            }

            for (int i=0; i<16; ++i){

                if (event.getSource() == Escolha[i]){

                    Escolha[i].setText(String.valueOf(Aleatorio[i]));///////////
                    Escolha[i].setEnabled(false);
                    Escolha[i].setVisible(true);
                    Numero_Click++;

                    if (Numero_Click == 1) Primeiro_Click = i;
                    if (Numero_Click == 2){
                        Segundo_Click = i;

                        ///////////////Clicks_não_conseguidos///////////////
                        if (Aleatorio[Primeiro_Click] != Aleatorio[Segundo_Click]){                                                       
                            pontos-=2;
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Memory.this, "Errado");

                            Escolha[Primeiro_Click].setText("");
                            Escolha[Segundo_Click].setText("");
                            Escolha[Primeiro_Click].setEnabled(true);
                            Escolha[Segundo_Click].setEnabled(true);                             

                        }  else {
                            Cont_Acertos++;
                            pontos+=10;
                        }

                        Numero_Click = 0;
                    }
                }
            }


            if (Cont_Acertos == 8){
                Numero_de_Vitorias++;
                Cont_Acertos = 0;
                if (pontos > pontos_Anterior) Maior_Pontuacao_do_Jogador = pontos;
                Fim_de_Jogo = true;
            }


            if (pontos < 0) pontos = 0;
            Pontuacao_do_Jogador.setText("Pontos: " + pontos);


            //if (Fim_de_Jogo == true){
            //Estatisticas_Jogo(Partidas_jogadas, Numero_de_Vitorias, Maior_Pontuacao_do_Jogador);
            //Fim_de_Jogo = false;
            //}           
        }
    }

    //void Estatisticas_Jogo(int Partidas_jogadas, int Numero_de_Vitorias, int Maior_Pontuacao_do_Jogador){

    // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Memory.this, "Partidas jogadas: " + Partidas_jogadas +
    //"\nVitórias: " + Numero_de_Vitorias +
    //"\nMaior Pontuação do Jogador: " + Maior_Pontuacao_do_Jogador);
    //}

    public static void main(String [] args){

        new Memory();

    }   
}
```

Comment: Sua dúvida não tem muito a ver com randomização, não é mesmo?

Comment: Não estou conseguindo randomizar imagens, somente números.

Comment: Sendo assim, você pode criar um `Map<Integer, String>`, randomizar os números, pegar o resultado e substituir pelo caminho de uma imagem.

Comment: Você poderia mostrar isso em código? Ou editar meu código?

Comment: Sim, eu estava mesmo querendo fazer isso, só que ontem a noite não dava, vou tentar fazer isso nas próximas horas (caso alguém não responda antes)

Comment: Valeu! Vou aguardar.

Comment: Seu código compilou de boa, isso facilita as coisas :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seu código compila e preenche os JButtons com números aleatórios, isso quer dizer que falta pouco para atingir seu objetivo, basicamente o que falta é colocar uma imagem no lugar de um número.

Uma forma direta de fazer isso é criar um vetor de imagens e usar o número aleatório como seu índice.

Por exemplo, se você fizer:

```
para(i=0; i<4; i++)
    imprime(i)
```

Você imprimirá quatro números inteiros, de 0 a 3.

Agora, se você fizer:

```
var imagens = {"endereco\imagem\0", 
               "endereco\imagem\1", 
               "endereco\imagem\2", 
               "endereco\imagem\3"} 
para(i=0; i<4; i++)
    mostra(imagens[i])
```

Você estará exibindo uma imagem no lugar do número. É isso que tem que ser feito.

Os exemplo acima estão em pseudocódigo para representar a ideia principal, o seu código reformulado para usar imagens ao invés de números seria o que está abaixo. Tudo que eu coloquei de novo no seu código eu comentei com a frase `//novo no seu código`, além disso eu removi tudo que estava com *warning* indicando que não estava sendo usado, para ficar mais compacto.

Código:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;

public class Memory extends JFrame{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    int pontos = 100; 

    Random RandomNumber = new Random(); 
    int Aleatorio[] = new int [16];
    int Posicao_do_vetor_Aleatorio[] = new int [16];

    private final JToolBar Barra_Ferramenta = new JToolBar();

    private final JButton Button_Novo_Jogo = new JButton("Novo Jogo");
    private final JButton[] Escolha = new JButton[16];
    private final Icon[] imgs = new Icon[8]; //novo no seu código

    private final JPanel Panel = new JPanel();
    private final JPanel Barra_de_Status = new JPanel();

    private final GridLayout Layout_do_Jogo = new GridLayout(4,4); 
    private final Font Fonte = new Font("Lucida Console", Font.BOLD, 36);

    private final JLabel Pontuacao_do_Jogador = new JLabel("Pontos: 100");

    public Memory() {
        super("Jogo da Memória");
        Barra_Ferramenta.add(Button_Novo_Jogo);
        add(Barra_Ferramenta, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        for (int i=0; i<16; ++i){
            Escolha[i] = new JButton();
            Panel.add(Escolha[i]);
            Escolha[i].setFont(Fonte);
            Escolha[i].setVisible(true);
        }
        Panel.setLayout(Layout_do_Jogo);
        add(Panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        Barra_de_Status.add(Pontuacao_do_Jogador);
        add(Barra_de_Status, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        Eventos_JogoDaMemoria Handler = new Eventos_JogoDaMemoria();
        for (int i=0; i<16; ++i){
            Escolha[i].addActionListener(Handler);
        }
        Button_Novo_Jogo.addActionListener(Handler);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);     
        this.setSize(500,500);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        //novo no seu código
        for(int i=0; i<imgs.length; i++) {
            imgs[i] = new ImageIcon("images/"+i+".jpg");
        }
    }

    private class Eventos_JogoDaMemoria implements ActionListener{
        int Cont_Acertos,Primeiro_Click,Segundo_Click;
        int Numero_Click, posi, cont, pontos_Anterior;
        boolean Novo_Jogo = true;
        boolean Re_Iniciar = false;
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){                       
            if (event.getSource() == Button_Novo_Jogo){
                Novo_Jogo = true;
                Re_Iniciar = false;
            }
            if (Novo_Jogo == true){ 
                Cont_Acertos = 0;
                pontos_Anterior = pontos;
                pontos = 100;
                Numero_Click = 0;
                posi = 0; cont = 16;
                Primeiro_Click = 0;
                Segundo_Click = 0;
                for (int i=0; i<16; ++i){
                    Escolha[i].setEnabled(true);
                }
                if (Re_Iniciar == false){

                    for (int i=0; i<16; ++i){
                        Posicao_do_vetor_Aleatorio[i] = i;
                    }
                    for (int i=0; i<8; ++i){

                        for (int j=0; j<2; ++j){
                            posi = RandomNumber.nextInt(cont);
                            Aleatorio[Posicao_do_vetor_Aleatorio[posi]] = i;

                            if (posi < cont){
                                for (int q=(posi+1); q<(cont); ++q){
                                    Posicao_do_vetor_Aleatorio[q-1] = Posicao_do_vetor_Aleatorio[q];
                                }
                            } cont--;
                        }
                    }
                }
                Novo_Jogo = false;
            }
            for (int i=0; i<16; ++i){
                if (event.getSource() == Escolha[i]){
                    Escolha[i].setIcon(imgs[Aleatorio[i]]);  //novo no seu código
                    Escolha[i].setEnabled(false);
                    Escolha[i].setVisible(true);
                    Numero_Click++;
                    if (Numero_Click == 1) Primeiro_Click = i;
                    if (Numero_Click == 2){
                        Segundo_Click = i;
                        ///////////////Clicks_não_conseguidos///////////////
                        if (Aleatorio[Primeiro_Click] != Aleatorio[Segundo_Click]){                                                       
                            pontos-=2;
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Memory.this, "Errado");
                            Escolha[Primeiro_Click].setIcon(null); //novo no seu código
                            Escolha[Segundo_Click].setIcon(null); //novo no seu código
                            Escolha[Primeiro_Click].setEnabled(true);
                            Escolha[Segundo_Click].setEnabled(true);                    
                        }  else {
                            Cont_Acertos++;
                            pontos+=10;
                        }
                        Numero_Click = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (Cont_Acertos == 8){
                Cont_Acertos = 0;
                if (pontos > pontos_Anterior) {
                }
            }
            if (pontos < 0) pontos = 0;
            Pontuacao_do_Jogador.setText("Pontos: " + pontos);

        }
    }
    public static void main(String [] args){
        new Memory();
    }   
}
```

PS: crie uma pasta chamada `images` na raiz do seu projeto e coloque arquivos jpegs com nomes que vão de `0.jpg` até `7.jpg`.

Além disso, tenho que lhe informar que seu código não segue as convenções definidas pelo [JavaBeans Standard](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html) que tem por objetivo padronizar a forma de escrever código e facilitar a comunicação entre os desenvolvedores.

Que diz por exemplo que:

- Variáveis devem ser escritas no padrão `camelCase` (Ex: `aleatorio`,  `numeroClick`, `contAcertos`). Logo, não se começa nomes de variáveis com maiúsculas nem se usa *underline* (`_`).
- Vetores devem ser declarados na forma `tipo[] nome`, enquanto você declara por exemplo `int Aleatorio[] = new int [16];` e deveria ser `int[] aleatorio = new int[16];`.

São apenas de algumas recomendações que lhe ajudará a se comunicar com outros desenvolvedores. Claro que não segui-las não vai fazer seu código quebrar, mas também não lhe traz nenhuma outra grande vantagem.

Não corrigi isso no código acima pois acredito que o mais importante é você saber disso nos seus código futuros.

Comment: Não consegui. Criei a pasta; coloquei as imagens, mas não deu certo. Parece que a pasta que criei não está sendo encontrada.

Comment: Poderia mostrar a exceção que foi lançada? Além disso, verifique se o nome da sua pasta está igual à minha : `images`, e não de `imagens`.

Comment: Não aparece nenhuma exceção; compila normal, mas não aparece as imagens ao se clicar nos botões.

Comment: Math, agora deu certo. Tirei esse código:         for(int i=0; i<imgs.length; i++) {
            imgs[i] = new ImageIcon("images/"+i+".jpg");
        }, porque não estava acessando a pasta "images"; e fiz conforme você orientou: var imagens = {"endereco\imagem\0", 
               "endereco\imagem\1", 
               "endereco\imagem\2", 
               "endereco\imagem\3"} 
para(i=0; i<4; i++)
    mostra(imagens[i]).